# DerivativesApi.GetModelviewProperties for subset of properties

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

The model viewer has the ability to get properties by passing a filter: viewer.model.getBulkProperties(dbIds, ['externalId', 'Category'], function) where we can limit the results to just the two properties 'externalId' and 'Category'.

It would be a huge benefit for us to have this same filtering capability from the model derivative api:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/

We have Revit files with 40,000+ parts, and it can take over 15 minutes to query for properties, but we are getting far more data than we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a reasonable enhancement. I logged it as an internal ticket DERI-4610.

If you have used [Extractor](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io) to download the whole SVF dataset to local  , you could try with extract the properties from **properties.db** (the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751920/how-properties-db-is-used-in-forge-viewer) tells more). This is a lite sql database which is actually used by Derivative API on Forge cloud. I'd think there is some smart ways to filter the specific properties by the db file.

Comment: I haven't used extractor, but am curious to try.  Our Revit model is 300 MB, but I expect the SVF file would be significantly smaller. Ideally we could ask the server for a very small payload of external ids.

Comment: Xiaodong, is there a limit to the number of simultaneous requests that we can make to get modelview properties?  I get responses that the model is locked at times with multiple requests.

Comment: @JGeerWM, it has some limitation as far as I know, not only for the endpoint of getting properties. How frequent you sent the each request, e.g. how many times per minute? I can inquiry with engineer team if it falls into current limitation.  In addition, I'd suggest with WebHook. It supports Data Management right now. I'd think it would support Model Derivative services. It would be more better than proactively checking from client side.

Comment: we were sending 6 simultaneous requests, but now have changed our code to send them in series to avoid the errors. Ideally, it would be great to send the requests in parallel AND limit the properties returned in the response to only those needed.

Comment: where is DERI-4610 on the roadmap for Forge? Is this something that will be worked on soon?

Comment: @JGeerWM, what I know is this wish has been in the plan that our engineer team will investigate, but I have not a further information about the exact progress, and I cannot either guarantee it would be exposed soon. While since it is a very useful function that can benefit many customers, I have highlighted the importance with engineer team, and put it in my watch list. We will notify if there is any news. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: is there any updated on DERI-4610 and being able to pass a filter for only which properties are returned?

Comment: Hi @JGeerWM, I got the info that it has been available for a while for getting property of single object. you can find an optional parameter 'objectid' with the endpoint https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/ . but it has not been available to support id array, which means it is not possible to get the properties of group of objects in one time. Sorry if this is a bad news to you

Comment: Hi @xiaodong-liang.  I'm hoping that we will be able to get a specific set of properties for a list of objects.  So, instead of collecting 100's of properties for 1000's of objects, we can just get the two we need.

Comment: Hi @JGeerWM, it makes sense to me with the requirement. Currently, this is not on the high priority in the scheduling of engineer team. If you have any important info, please email to forge.help@autodesk.com. I will also try to push engineer team this feature could be exposed soon. Sorry for the inconvenience at this moment.

Comment: this has become quite an issue for us, with wait times of almost 2 hours from the first 202 response to the final 200 response.  The result's content is over 185 MB in size.  I'll reach out to support again.

Comment: hi @JGeerWM, could you send us the URN of the model to forge.help@autodesk.com ?  It will be more helpful if you could also share  a copy of the test mode (after removing the confidential information)  We will  diagnose what dragged the performance.

Comment: the urn has been sent